# I think I need an array, but I don't know how to build this

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I've a worksheet named "GetData". In this worksheet are more columns.

```
A(Names)|B...   |C(Center)
++++++++|+++++++|+++++++++
Alpha   |       |100-Base
Beta    |       |110-2nd
Charly  |       |100-Base
```

Now I want sort them into another worksheet named "Overview" like this:

```
A(Grouped)
++++++++++
100-Base
Alpha
Charly
110-2nd
Beta
```

I think I need an array, but I don't know how to build this. I tried this for beginning:

```
     Sub unique4()
        Dim arr As New Collection, a
        Dim aFirstArray() As Variant
        Dim i As Long

        Dim LastRow As Long
        LastRow = Worksheets("GetData").Cells(Worksheets("GetData").Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

        aFirstArray() = Worksheets("GetData").Range("C2:C" & LastRow).Value


        On Error Resume Next
        For Each a In aFirstArray
           arr.Add a, a
        Next

        For i = 1 To arr.Count
           Cells(i, 1) = arr(i)
        Next
     End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: Here is how I would do it: 1)sort data on column C. 2) iterate through column C.3) on each new value in column I would redim preserve a single dimension array adding one new space 4) put the value of C and a "|" then for each column A that has the same column C I would add column A and "|" so it was "100-Base|Alpha|Charly". 5) iterate through the array after filling splitting on the "|" putting the values in the order desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one without arrays,

```
Sub unique4()

Dim i As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim tws As Worksheet

Set tws = Sheets("Sheet2")'Change to desired sheet output name.
j = 1
With Sheets("GetData")
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To lastrow
        If i <> 1 Then
            If .Cells(i, 3) <> .Cells(i - 1, 3) Then
                tws.Cells(j, 1) = .Cells(i, 3)
                j = j + 1
                tws.Cells(j, 1) = .Cells(i, 1)
                j = j + 1
            Else
                tws.Cells(j, 1) = .Cells(i, 1)
                j = j + 1
            End If
        Else
            tws.Cells(j, 1) = .Cells(i, 3)
            j = j + 1
            tws.Cells(j, 1) = .Cells(i, 1)
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

One Caveat, you will need to sort the data on column C to make work.

Answer (score 0):

this should solve your issue with just an Excel formula. If you want a vba solution, that is of course possible too.

In your new sheet, in column A Setup it like:

Column A

```
1
1
2
2
3
3
```

You can get this format by entering the following in Cell A3 and pull it down as far as you need (set Cell A1, A2 with a value of 1).

`=A1+1`

In Column B you are going to enter an Indirect Formula. In cell B1, put this:

`=INDIRECT("Sheet1!A"&A1)`

In Cell B2, put this:

`=INDIRECT("Sheet1!C"&A2)`

Column A will keep track of which row to pull from, then the indirect formula will dynamically build the formula to get the value. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Without sorting any data or something like that:

```
Sub test()
Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, chkB As Boolean
Dim wsGet As Worksheet, wsPut As Worksheet
Set wsGet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Set wsPut = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
Const FirstRow As Long = 3
LastRow = wsGet.Range("C" & wsGet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = FirstRow To LastRow
  chkB = True
  For j = FirstRow To i - 1
    If wsGet.Cells(i, 3) = wsGet.Cells(j, 3) Then chkB = False: Exit For
  Next
  If chkB Then
    k = k + 1
    wsPut.Cells(k, 1) = wsGet.Cells(i, 3)
    For j = i To LastRow
      If wsGet.Cells(j, 3) = wsGet.Cells(i, 3) Then
        k = k + 1
        wsPut.Cells(k, 1) = wsGet.Cells(j, 1)
      End If
    Next
  End If
Next
End Sub
```